# Adding figure and text in a cell of a table

Tags: tables, floats, text, cell

I am making a table which has some figures in it. Two of the cells need to have some text as well on the bottom of the figure (It's not caption, so does not need to have fig. number).The text is getting displayed alongside and not getting centered. {The text is "2X in cascade"}

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\begin{document}
    \begin{landscape}
        \begin{table}[]
            \centering
            \caption{Architectural schematics of the presented front-ends with structural details of the core amplifiers.}
            \label{tab:my-table}
            \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
                \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
                    \hline
                    & FE-I   & FE-II  & FE-III  & FE-IV \\ \hline
                    \raisebox{0.5\height}{\rotatebox[origin=l]{90}{{Architecture}}}
                    & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\includegraphics[scale=0.28]{Figures/1}} 
                    & \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{Figures/2}  \\ \hline
                    \raisebox{0.4\height}{\rotatebox[origin=l]{90}{{Core Amplifier}}} 
                    & \raisebox{0.1\height}{\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{Figures/3}} {\centering 2X in cascade}
                    & \raisebox{0.1\height}{\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{Figures/3}} {\centering 2X in cascade}
                    & \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{Figures/4}    
                    & \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{Figures/5}  \\ \hline
                \end{tabular}%
            }
        \end{table}
    \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: use raisebox for the text also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `c`-columns does not accept more than one line. You either need a `p`-column, or a `\parbox` inside the cell. However, the easiest is to add a new row and remove the `\raisebox`es.

If you need the pictures to be centred, you cannot use the second row tricks (or you can, but need to load [multirow](https://ctan.org/pkg/multirow)). Instead, I suggest you define a command the split the cells in columns 2 and 3, by nesting a table inside the cell and align the new table at the bottom baseline. See example 2.

It is not necessary to load `lscape` when you load `pdflscape`:

**Example 1 - new row**
[image]

```
\documentclass[demo]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{pdflscape, array}

\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}

\begin{document}
    \begin{landscape}
        \begin{table}[]
            \centering
            \caption{Architectural schematics of the presented front-ends with structural details of the core amplifiers.}
            \label{tab:my-table}
            \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
                \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
                    \hline
                    & FE-I   & FE-II  & FE-III  & FE-IV \\ \hline
                    \raisebox{0.25\height}{\rotatebox[origin=l]{90}{{Architecture}}}
                    & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\includegraphics[scale=0.28]{Figures/1}} 
                    & \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{Figures/2}  \\ \hline
                    \raisebox{0.15\height}{\rotatebox[origin=l]{90}{{Core Amplifier}}} 
                    & \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{Figures/3}
                    & \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{Figures/3}
                    & \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{Figures/4}    
                    & \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{Figures/5}  \\ 
                    & 2X in cascade
                    & 2X in cascade
                    &&\\
                    \hline
                \end{tabular}%
            }
        \end{table}
    \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

**Example 2 - nested tabulars**

[image]

```
\documentclass[demo]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{pdflscape, array}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}

% Multi-line left-aligned text with manual line breaks.
% The base line of the whole is at the top row.
\newcommand*{\tstack}[1]{%
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\begingroup        % Add | after the `c` to have vertical lines 
    \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1}%
    \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}%
  \endgroup
}}

\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}

\begin{document}
    \begin{landscape}
        \begin{table}[thb]
            \centering
            \caption{Architectural schematics of the presented front-ends with structural details of the core amplifiers.}
            \label{tab:my-table}
            \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
                \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
                    \hline
                    & FE-I   & FE-II  & FE-III  & FE-IV \\ \hline
                    \raisebox{0.25\height}{\rotatebox[origin=l]{90}{{Architecture}}}
                    & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\includegraphics[scale=0.28]{Figures/1}} 
                    & \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{Figures/2}  \\ \hline
                    \raisebox{0.15\height}{\rotatebox[origin=l]{90}{{Core Amplifier}}} 
                    & \tstack{\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{Figures/3} \\2X in cascade}
                    & \tstack{\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{Figures/3} \\ 2X in cascade}
                    & \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{Figures/4}    
                    & \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{Figures/5}  \\ 
                    \hline
                \end{tabular}%
            }
        \end{table}
    \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
There is a slight issue with the answer you proposed, as you see Fig 4 and Fig 5 are no more centered vertically. Is there a way to center these figures vertically?

Comment: See example 2 in the updated answer

Comment: Thank you once again. That's exactly what I wanted. But I see now, in second row and first three columns there is no border. Is it because of using nested tabular?

Comment: @Zulqar I have fixed the vertical lines.

Comment: Thank you very much. It's exactly what I was looking for.