# How to make a tight grid of many images?

Tags: tables, graphics, floats, subfloats

What is the best way in LaTeX to typeset a grid of images with no space between the images and labels along the outer edges such as in the image below? A table? subfigures? anything else?

[image: Example how it should look like]

Comment: A table, look at this answer for ideas: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/528136/9632. Is your picture of equal widths and heights, or do you need to scale them into a table grid?

Comment: Thanks!  All single images are of the same size if this is what you mean. Ideally, the whole grid should scale to text width automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is six pictures. You set `\tabcolsep` to 0 and back up each row a little bit to remove space between rows and columns:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}

\begin{document}
        \begin{table}
            \centering
            \caption{Picture grid.\label{tab:picturegrid}}
                \begin{tabular}{ccc}
                     \includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{homer-simpson.png}
                    & \includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{homer-simpson.png}
                    & \includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{homer-simpson.png}\\[-4pt]
                     \includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{homer-simpson.png}
                    & \includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{homer-simpson.png}
                    & \includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{homer-simpson.png}\\[-4pt]
                \end{tabular}%
        \end{table}
\end{document}
```